# Equation of Motion in Non-Planar Rotation

Tags: kinematics, vectors, rotational-kinematics

I'm trying to understand the equations of motion for a rigid body that is rotating and I am a bit stuck.

For a rigid body, assuming planar rotation (not necessary to be uniform), we can express the tangential and centripetal acceleration components of the acceleration at a point at radial distance $r$ as follows:

$$\vec a = (r \times \ddot \theta + 2r\times \dot \theta)\hat \theta + (\ddot r-r \times\dot \theta ^2)\hat r $$

Where the cross-product allows dealing with a general 3D case for 3D radius vector. For a rigid body that is only rotating, we can assume $\dot r=0, \ddot r=0$ for any points on that body.

Now if we are to assume that the same point on the rigid body undergoes general rotation (with no translation of the center of rotation), are the above equations still valid? I.E. if I say:
$$ \dot\theta = b\vec v \space\space\space and \space\space\space \frac{db}{dt}\neq 0, \frac{d\vec v}{dt} \neq 0 $$

My understanding is the above equations are not valid since they assume the vector derivative is zero but since the calculation involves a cross-product I was confused if that is actually true.

If the above equations don't hold, what are the equations that describe the accelerations in a co-rotating frame when the rotation vector is not constrained to a plane? For my work specifically, I am dealing with a rotation vector that prescribes a cone (i.e. precession and some minimal nutation).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precession

Answers specific to precessional motions are nice but a more general solution would be preferred (or if you could point me to some references that would be good as well).

Comment: $\dot\theta = a\vec{v}$ if a is acceleration check the units

Comment: Good point, that is a bit confusing. I meant $a$ to just generally be representative of a scalar variable. Changed it now.

Comment: Why are there cross-products in the components of your 1st equation? Aren't $r$ and $\dot \theta$ scalar variables?